# JAXB Umarshaller error

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, jersey

I am trying to generate Object from XML using JAXB. First, I created the objects out of supplied schema and packaged them into 1 .jar. Now I am using this simple test program (after it refused to work with Jersey):

```
import org.editeur.ns.onix._3_0.reference.*;

public class Mapping {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the Onix message:");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            String request = reader.readLine();
            request.trim();
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(request);
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.editeur.ns.onix._3_0.reference");
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();           
            ONIXMessage message = (ONIXMessage) unmarshaller.unmarshal(stringReader);   
            stringReader.close();
            //System.out.println(message.getHeader().getSentDateTime());
            //System.out.println(message.getHeader().getMessageNote().get(0).getValue());
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I use the following test XML-string (withouts spaces or line breaks):

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ONIXMessage release="3.0"><Header><Sender><SenderName>Global Bookinfo</SenderName><ContactName>Jane King, +1 555 321 7654</ContactName><EmailAddress>jbk@globalbookinfo.com</EmailAddress></Sender><Addressee><AddresseeName>BooksBooksBooks.com</AddresseeName></Addressee><MessageNumber>231</MessageNumber><SentDateTime>20100510T1115-0400</SentDateTime><MessageNote>Sample message</MessageNote></Header><Product><RecordReference>com.globalbookinfo.onix.01734529</RecordReference><NotificationType>03</NotificationType><RecordSourceType>04</RecordSourceType><RecordSourceIdentifier><RecordSourceIDType>06</RecordSourceIDType><IDValue>0614141800001</IDValue></RecordSourceIdentifier><RecordSourceName>Global Bookinfo</RecordSourceName><ProductIdentifier><ProductIDType>03</ProductIDType><IDValue>9780007232833</IDValue></ProductIdentifier><ProductIdentifier><ProductIDType>15</ProductIDType><IDValue>9780007232833</IDValue></ProductIdentifier></Product></ONIXMessage>

But it gives me the same error:

    javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"ONIXMessage"). Expected elements are <{http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference}Addressee>,<{http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference}AddresseeIDType>,<{http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference}AddresseeIdentifier>,<{http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference}AddresseeName>,<{http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference}Affiliation>,<{http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference}AgentIDType>,<{http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference}AgentIdentifier>,<{http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference}AgentName>,<{http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference}AgentRole>,<{http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference}AlternativeName>,<{http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference}AncillaryContent>,<{http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference}AncillaryContentDescription>,<{http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference}AncillaryContentType>,<{http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference}Audience>,<{http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference}AudienceCode> 

...


        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:648)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:236)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:231)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:105)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1051)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:484)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:465)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:135)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:626)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3104)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:921)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:200)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:173)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:137)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:194)
        at Mapping.main(Mapping.java:19)
```

When I was generating classes with XJC, no problems were detected. 
But when parsing XML, it seems to ask for a correct element. But according to the Schema, the first element (root) is ONIXMessage tag, which is there. 
When I am using Jersey, it does not even show anything - just returns null contents of ONIXMessage root tag.

What is wrong? How can I fix it? Any help appreciated.

Update.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "header",
    "product"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "ONIXMessage")
public class ONIXMessage {

    @XmlElement(name = "Header", required = true)
    protected Header header;
    @XmlElement(name = "Product", required = true)
    protected List<Product> product;
    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    protected String refname;
    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    protected String shortname;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String datestamp;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String sourcetype;
    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "anySimpleType")
    protected String sourcename;
    @XmlAttribute(required = true)
    protected String release;
```

This is the root class generated by XJC. Seems like it should be. I dont know schema well, but in schema there seems to be no such element definition as ONIXMessage - but I cant unserstand where XJC gets it from if there is no defenition of Root element. Here is the start of XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference" xmlns="http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="ONIX_BookProduct_CodeLists.xsd"/>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="ONIX_XHTML_Subset.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="Addressee">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:choice>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="AddresseeIdentifier"/>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="AddresseeName"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="AddresseeName"/>
                </xs:choice>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="ContactName"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="EmailAddress"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="refname">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
                        <xs:enumeration value="Addressee"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="shortname">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
                        <xs:enumeration value="addressee"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attributeGroup ref="generalAttributes"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="AddresseeIdentifier">
```

These are 1st successors of the should-be-root ONIXMessage tag, but there seems to be no mentioning about the ONIXMessage tag itself.

Comment: Most probably `ONIXMessage` class is not annotated with `@XmlRootElement`. Can you show the relvant part of the XSD perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML document your are unmarshalling does not appear to conform to the XML schema you used to generate your model.  You could try one of the following:

- Validate the input XML against the XML schema to see where it is invalid.
- Populate the Java objects and marshal them out to XML to see what the input XML should look like.

Comment: Thank you. Your approach seemed to work. I used #2. Generally the problem was: I needed to add this to ONIXMessage tag this attribute -  xmlns="http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference". Do you know why it requires a namespace like that?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess would be that when you generate the context[1] I would pass as a parameter the class you want to parse to (ONIXMessage).
And the I would try with a code like this:

```
public <T> T toObject(final String requestXML, final Class<T> type)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] bytes = requestXML.getBytes("UTF-8"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        final ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(bais);
        SAXSource source = new SAXSource(inputSource);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<T> jaxbElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(source, type);

        return (T) JAXBIntrospector.getValue(jaxbElement);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Note where I put `<T>` there should go your class ONIXMessage.

[1]http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class...)

Comment: Have just tried - no success. It creates ONIXMessage, but all contents are null.

Answer (score 0):

Two things about generating the Onix schema into Java classes you need to watch out for.

1. (this is a pain) Because the Onix schema has duplicate names for different parts of the schema all over the place, you get a lot of classes with the catch-all "content" object instead of a proper object tree like you'd expect.  The data is still there, but it it's not nearly as easy to work with.  I don't know a way to get around this short of going through each one and manually moving the xmlrefelements from the content to their own attributes.
2. If your Onix message doesn't have the uri in it, you need to edit the package-info.java file in the root of your generated Onix classes folder and remove everything between the quotes in the XmlSchema namespace annotation.

> @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "",
>   elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)

EDIT:  looks like you can switch to an expiremental binding mode that generates much better class files, but requires adding a configuration element to the schema (though otherwise doesn't change it) during the build process.
https://jaxb.java.net/2.1.2/docs/vendorCustomizations.html#simple